# Is there anyone who can see what I missing in this v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have V-dialog as modal in extern component, but for some reasone is doen't work as expected.
I want to say I using Vue 3 and Vuetfy 3, and I check posts about this but doesn't helping.

I think problem is because props which I provide to child component was not updated in parent component when that is case in child component.

This is how I call that modal component:

```
  <VehiclesNoteModal
    :id="this.id"
    v-model="noteModal.show"
    :noteFetch="noteFetch"
  ></VehiclesNoteModal>
```

And this is my child component:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="this.modelValue" width="500">
    <v-card>
      <v-toolbar title="Unos napomene"></v-toolbar>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form @submit.prevent="submit" ref="frm">
          <v-text-field
            variant="solo"
            v-model="item.noteTitle"
            label="Naslov"
            :rules="[this.$required]"
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-textarea
            variant="solo"
            v-model="item.note"
            label="Napomena"
            :rules="[this.$required, this.$max(150)]"
            no-resize
            counter="150"
          ></v-textarea>
          <v-card-actions class="justify-space-between">
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
              type="submit"
              variant="elevated"
              color="#306bac"
              class="btnAdd mr-3"
              ><v-icon size="20px" class="mdi mdi-plus"></v-icon> Dodaj</v-btn
            >
            <v-btn
              variant="elevated"
              @click.prevent="this.$emit('update:modelValue', false)"
            >
              <v-icon size="25px" color="#306bac">mdi mdi-close</v-icon>
              Zatvori</v-btn
            >
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: Boolean, // Change the prop name to modelValue
    id: {
      required: true,
    },
    noteFetch: {
      required: true,
      type: Function,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        noteTitle: null,
        note: null,
        vehicleId: this.id,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      axios
        .post(this.$API_BASE_URL + "/vehicles/notes/add", this.item)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.noteFetch();
          this.$emit("update:modelValue", false); // Emit the update:modelValue event
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.btnAdd {
  color: white;
}
.v-toolbar {
  background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

I tried some syntax from Vue 2 and Vuetify 2, but nothing....
I hope anyone can help me with this.

I also tried using :show.sync but nothing.

Comment: Remove the `this` in `v-model="this.modelValue"` - there is no `this` in template, it's just `v-model="modelValue"`

Comment: When I do that I get this error:
`VueCompilerError: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable.
Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead.`

Comment: That is prop which I get from parent element

Comment: Prop is readonly, you cannot used it on a v-model value

Comment: Is there a way to replace this then? I think this syntax works in Vue 2 and Vuetify 2